# Getting object not found error when calling Aggregate Function with FUN=count

Tags: r

When I call the aggregate function I got the error `Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'count' not found`

I have tried updating R as well as using plyr package, but the later does not give me the result I want.

```
aggregate(soybean.table, by=list(soybean$seed.tmt, soybean$germination), FUN=count)
```

Comment: I think you need `length` instead of `count`  `count` is from `dplyr` and it requires a data.framae as input

Comment: @akrun phrase it like an answer and post it because that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is one function in `dplyr` and in `plyr`.  The `dplyr/plyr` `count` requires a `data.frame/data.table/tbl_df` as input.  With `aggregate`, the option to find the number of rows would be `length`

```
aggregate(soybean.table, by=list(soybean$seed.tmt, soybean$germination), FUN= length)
```

As a reproducible example

```
aggregate(mtcars, list(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am), FUN = length)
```

It may be better to select one column and group by the column of interest as the `length` would be the same as long as the grouping variables are the same e.g.

```
aggregate(mpg ~ vs + am, mtcars, FUN = length)
```

Or to have a different column name

```
aggregate(cbind(Count = seq_along(mpg))~ vs + am, mtcars, FUN = length)
```